# Associative array with dynamic key in Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, smarty

The problem appears to be quite simple:

I have the following code in my smarty template (inside a section):

```
 {$content.automatisms[id].id}

    {section name=sctionsID loop=$content.actions[57]}
        Hi!
    {/section}
```

The first line is returning the current integer (56 & 57) in this case. It works perfectly.

What I am trying to do now, is using this value as a key to access a value inside an array. "Hi" gets printed in the example above. But as soon as I try to replace the "57" it stops working.

Many thanks in advance,
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
{$content.automatisms[id].id}

{section name=sctionsID loop=$content.actions[57]}
    {$content.actions[57][sctionsID]}
{/section}
```

Comment: The goal is to replace the "57" with the content of the first line ;)